# CSS Hover different on/off transition

Tags: css, hover

Please can somebody explain the following.

I believe that a transition can be triggered by, for example, hovering.

My hover style should contain the CSS that I want my element to have at the end of the transition (in this case color:red).

The browser will then transition from the original css to the hover css using the time duration specified on the *original unhovered* css.

```css
a{
    color:blue;
    transition: color 1s;
}
a:hover{
    color:red;
}
```

This works perfectly.

BUT what if I want the transition from non-hover to hover to be instant? From experimenting, it appears to work if I add `transition: color 0s;` to my hover css. But to me this doesn't make sense, because my *a* css still has the 1second duration. If anything, I would expect adding this would cause a 1s transition on hover and a 0s transition when the mouse is moved away.

Can somebody explain where my understanding is wrong?

Comment: to be sure, you want the transition from non-hover to hover to be instant, and from hover to non-hover to be 1 sec?

Comment: @MansurKhan Yep that's correct

Comment: surely if you wanted it to be instant you remove you transition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but Justbees has given the answer I was particularly looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the duration of the transition to that state.
So adding 0 to hover means it will be a 0s transition to the hover state and then a 1s transition back to non-hover.

If it's only on the original non-hover then the transition applies to both.

Answer (score 2):

this is the situation. If you make that opposite, it works perfectly.

```
<a href="#">Test</a>
```

css:

```css
a{
  color:blue;
  transition: color 0s;
}

a:hover{
  transition: color 1s;
  color: peachpuff;
}
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wWFDh/).

Enjoy!

Comment: @Adrift just see that your transition of 0s was in hovered a and 1s in normal a which was opposite to what Lars wanted. Then when I did a vice versa on that in my answer, it's just what he wants.